# Python file that recursively executes itself

Tags: python

I want to make my program recursively call itself, so I tried this. However, for some reason even though the code does execute I get the desired effect only in Pycharms debugger. Any ideas?

os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable, **file**] + sys.argv)

Note: I don't really need to pass any arguments to the new iteration

In my code I have an object called mcp. When this objects internal state changes to restart I need to start the main function all over again. Note that the internal state of the system is correct. I managed to work around it by using os.system("")

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

mcp = Mcp()
mcp.start()

while mcp.internal_state == State.Running.value:
    time.sleep(1)

if mcp.internal_state == State.ShutDown.value or mcp.internal_state == State.Restart.value:
    mcp.wait()

if mcp.internal_state == State.Restart.value:
    #os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable, __file__] + sys.argv)
    os.system("Python rinzler.py")
```

Comment: ``execv`` replaces the *entire* program with the old one. Is there any reason why you don't just use an infinite loop (``while True:``) in the top-level program?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]? What exactly happens when you execute this outside of the PyCharm debugger? How do you execute this?